# Intellisense of VS Code is poor

Tags: javascript, class, visual-studio-code, intellisense

Hi I am using VS Code for quite some while and it's Suggestions of, for Example Class properties or methods is kinda poor. I wanted to check out if this is suppose to be like that or if that is an Issue only for me. I am using it mostly for frontend development with JS/TS or JS Frameworks and often when I install npm packages and import them Intellisense is not showing me their properties which is very lame because this should be in my opinion the number one support it should provide. Many other features of it are great so I would like to keep using it but if that is the supposed behaviour I think I have to switch to a new IDE.

For Example I am using Three JS right now which has in my opinion a very solid Object Oriented Style where it is very essential to know what properties and methods a class has, though Intellisense kind of does not know unless I have typed it once manually, e.g:

I have imported Three JS as follows at the top of the file:
`import * as THREE from '../node_modules/three/src/Three.js';`

and I am looking for TextureLoader which suppose to be a method of the THREE class which it is when I type it manually, everything works fine though VS Code does not seem to recognize it which is very poor behaviour for an IDE. The Suggestions you see in the Image are the only ones it suggests me. (There is textureLoader typed with a small t at the beginning, but that is because I have used a variable with that name) so VS Code only suggests me things that I have typed already. And

[image]

I have checked all the related Posts Stackoverflow is showing me but nothing is related to this topic and All the bug fixes only are related when you have a literal bug in VSCode, but I am not even sure this is an actual bug. Also many people love VSCode and claim it is the best free IDE and I am wondering why if it even can't provide the most fundamental things. I remember Eclipse for Java where it showed you every attribute and method of a class.

I thought it could be a problem of JS since it has no types but I think I remember that Webstorm provided the suggestions correct for JS

So my question is, is that expected? Should the Intellisense mechanism not detect Methods and variables defined in a imported class and just provide you with a list of all of them?

Comment: It also does not have to be the TextureLoader() method, the THREE Object has hundreds of exports in it which are all not listed in the Suggestion box for some reason.

Comment: Well libraries have to supply VS with TS type information. A library can do that if it wants, or it can opt not to. Without that, because JavaScript is a dynamic language, it's difficult for VSCode to do anything for you.

Comment: Yeah but If I imagine correcty, in webstorm that was not an Issue for JS files and classes

Answer (score 1):

So I have found out that it is not just a problem with my VS Code. VS Code just cannot know what types or methods are available for a class or object. I thought it might have some parsing capabilities running through an class and picking up it's methods to display it in the suggestion/code completion box, but I guess this is to overkill.

So Type completion is available if you use Typescript. For me event though I am using Typescript together with Three.js I still haven't had any useful suggestions in my VSC. So I have found out that the IDE relies on the type definition files "[name].d.ts" where types for Typescript are defined. These should be provided by the author of libraries/ packages you use.

If their are not there is a repo where you can check if such types are available on the npm registry found under @types so for me I had to manually run:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/three
```

which installed me a new directory under @types/three with a d.ts for every three JS Module.

when you do then an import like:

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
```

typescript knows to also look for declaration files d.ts under "node_modules/@types/three" I guess

So to summarize:

- No code completion because of js dynamic type system like [python, ruby]
- You can have code completion using typescript since it has static types like [java, #c]
- There must a [name].d.ts file provided telling the ide how a class is defined.
- For build-in things like the 'dom' and 'window' it is provided by default when installing typescript

correct me if I'm wrong